# Shorthand/shortcuts for IF statements excel/spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have about a hundred nested functions that defines the value of a cell.

I want to add another one that make that nested one return 0 under certain conditions, and itself under other.

Which means that in a single cell, my if statement becomes:

=If([one_hundred_nested_functions]<0,[one_hundred_nested_functions,0)

As you can see, this statement makes me write the nested functions 2 times in the single statement: one for evaluating and one for value_if_true.

Does spreadsheets or excel have any shorthand or other (non-custom) function for that?

Comment: Why not just do `if` on the cell with the value?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output along with the logic of the formula.  It's likely there's a better way instead of 100 if statements.  This really seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: if you're only looking for a quick solution, the MIN function would work for this: `=MIN([one_hundred_nested_functions],0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific shorthand. But in numeric outputs,`TEXT` function maybe used. So,

```
=If([one_hundred_nested_functions]<0,[one_hundred_nested_functions],0)
```

can  be simplified to:

```
=TEXT([one_hundred_nested_functions],"\0;-#.0")*1
```

You can also use `MIN` in this case:

```
=MIN([one_hundred_nested_functions],0)
```