# If x is y then z, else x without repeating x in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dry

In a cell, is it possible to do `if(x=y, z, x)` without having to repeat `x` in the value_if_false argument? Whether there is a way of using if() to make this work or another function doesn't matter, and there isn't a specific formula I'm struggling with as I come across this blocker quite often (hence posting).

To help illustrate the need, if we take x as a complex or more advanced formula, such as

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E$6:Q$6 < EoMONTH($P$4,0), "Not Active", IF(E$6:Q$6<$Q$4 + ISBLANK($Q$4) > 0,
COUNTIF({'Data'!$B$3:$B&'Data'!$I$3:$I&'Data'!$K$3:$K},$B$4&$C9&E$6:Q$6), "Not Active")))
```

and I wanted to put an if statement in there that changed the result *only if a condition was true*, the formula would more than double in size due to having to reference x twice:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(E$6:Q$6 < EoMONTH($P$4,0), "Not Active", IF(E$6:Q$6<$Q$4 + ISBLANK($Q$4) > 0,
COUNTIF({'Data'!$B$3:$B&'Data'!$I$3:$I&'Data'!$K$3:$K},$B$4&$C9&E$6:Q$6), "Not Active"))) = 0, "No data", IF(E$6:Q$6 < EoMONTH($P$4,0), "Not Active", IF(E$6:Q$6<$Q$4 + ISBLANK($Q$4) > 0,
COUNTIF({'Data'!$B$3:$B&'Data'!$I$3:$I&'Data'!$K$3:$K},$B$4&$C9&E$6:Q$6), "Not Active"))))
```

This is just an example (the code is irrelevant), I'm trying to keep my formulas neat, tidy and efficient so that handing off to others is easier. Then I'm also mindful that it is calculating the same complex formula twice, which would probably slow the spreadsheet down especially when iterated throughout a spreadsheet.

Interested to hear the community thoughts and suggestions on this, hopefully I was clear in explaining it. :)

Comment: I'd put the calculation of `x` in a separate column, and perhaps hide it.  You can then refer to it twice in your conditional expression with only a few extra characters, and no actual duplication of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks jasonharper. In some scenarios this is a reasonable solution. It is however at the whims of the structure of the spreadsheet and increases the complexity through chaining formulas. If there's a way of resolving without commandeering another column that would be preferable :)

Comment: The 'best' answer to this would be that Google add the LET function that Excel 365 has to Sheets, then you could wrap your IF inside this, refer to your complex expression once, give it a short name and then use the short name twice in the IF statement. However in the meantime the only way of dealing with this (other than the helper column idea and only in some contexts) is the use of IFERROR, and reworking the logic of your IF statement so that it generates an error for certain results that you then trap - very difficult to elaborate without knowing the specific context.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72792845/shorthand-shortcuts-for-if-statements-excel-spreadsheet/72792910#72792910

Answer (score 2):

The only simple way to achieve this would be with the use of helper columns. They don't need to be in the same sheet as your main equation, but they do need to be within that same spreadsheet as a whole (ie you could have a sheet named "calc" that's specifically used to calculate intermediate steps and set "variables" by referencing those cells).

The only other option (which gets a bit complicated) is to create a custom function within Google Apps Script. For example, if you wanted to calculate `(B1*A4)/C5` in multiple places, you could create a custom function like this:

```js
/**
* Returns a calculation using cells A4, B1, and C5.
* @return A calculation using cells A4, B1, and C5.       
* @customfunction
*/
function x() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MainSheet');
  var val1 = ss.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var val2 = ss.getRange('A4').getValue();
  var val3 = ss.getRange('C5').getValue();

  return (val1*val2)/val3;
}
```

Then in your sheet, you could use this within a formula like this:

```js
=if(A1="yes", x(), "no")
```

This custom function could obviously be altered to fit one's needs (ex taking in arguments to define the cells that the calculations should be done on instead of hard coding them, etc).

Other than this, there is currently no way to define variables within a formula itself.

Comment: Thanks for the expansion and confirmation. To assign your script solution to the example (syntactically speaking) just in case anyone was wondering, it would be `=IF( x() >= 0, x(), "Less than zero outcome")` which wouldn't resolve running the complex formula twice but would resolve the visual complexity of the code for handing off to others.

To completely resolve I would have to use helper columns on a separate tab.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to a certain extent, using `TEXT`'s [Meta Instructions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#meta_instructions), if you're using numbers and simple math conditions.

| x | y | z | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 5 | 10 |

```
=TEXT(A3,"[="&B3&"]0;"&C3&"")
```

| x | y | z | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 10 | 5 | 5 |

As long as your complex formula returns a number for `x`(or the output can be coerced to a number), this should be possible and it avoids repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I would love if there was like a DECODE or NVL type function you could use so that you didn't need to repeat the original statement multiple times.

However, in many cases, when I encounter this, I can often reference another cell. Not in the way that has been suggested already, where the formula exists in another cell, but rather that the decision to perform the formula is based on another cell.

For example, using your values, lets assume the formula ((if(x=y, z, x)) only gets calculated when column 'w' is populated. Maybe column 'w' is a key component of the formula. Then you can write the formula as: if(w="",z,x). It's not exactly the same as testing the answer to the equation first and doesn't work in all situations, but in many cases I can find another field that's of key relevance to the formula that lets me get around this.